# Java- Log4j problems loading main class

Tags: java, cmd, log4j

I have the following structure

```
|
|src
    |oata
         |HelloWorld.java
|build
      |classes
|lib
      |log4j-1.2.17.jar
```

I am working on windows, and compiling and running with windows console. Apart from adding the log4j-1.2.17.jar file in my project, there is nothing else that I have done related to log4j in my computer (like add it an classpath in the environmental variables or anything else, none of these things I have done). My HelloWorld.java looks like this (same from [Tutorial Hello World](https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html#prepare))

```
package oata;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;

public class HelloWorld {
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloWorld.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        logger.info("Hello World");
    }
}
```

I compile with the following line and it creates HelloWorld.class in build/classes/oata/HelloWorld.class (when creating the .class file it adds a new folder called oata inside classes)

```
javac -d ./build/classes -cp ./lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar ./src/oata/HelloWorld.java
```

Then I try to run the .class with

```
java -cp ./lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar;./build/classes/oata oata.HelloWorld
```

But I got this error
   Error: Could not find or load main class oata.HelloWorld

I am missing something, and tried with other other solutions gave it in stackoverflow, but nothing has worked. So I do not have idea what could be, because I am using basic configuration and accoding to Log4j documentation there is not much to do apart from adding the .jar in the project.
It will be a great help to point out where I am failing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe try `java -cp ./lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar;./build/classes/ oata.HelloWorld`?

Comment: Great!!!! Thanks, I cannot believe it was so simple. Thank you, you save my life.